# Mixing Entity Framework with Stored Procedures - Connection Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I'm using Code First Entity Framework to do all of my database retrieval. Unfortunately, where I work they have mandated that any updates/inserts/deletes must be accomplished using stored procedures.

I started by doing the following:

```
public partial class MyContext
{
    public void AddStatus(int id, string status)
    {
        var connection = (SqlConnection)this.Database.Connection;

        if( connection.State != ConnectionState.Open )
            connection.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        // ...

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

This worked fine for a while, until I came across a scenario where I needed to retrieve data from my database directly after this code, using the same context:

```
MyContext db = new MyContext();

db.AddStatus(1, "Open");

var item = db.Items.Find(1);
```

I got the following error:

`ArgumentException - EntityConnection can only be constructed with a closed DbConnection.`

Is there any way I can mix code like this or do I have to create another connection to my database? Will I run into problems if I create a new connection such as Distributed Transactions if I need a transaction scope?

Comment: Why not just use the built in proc mapping mechanism?

Comment: What proc mapping? Does it work in Code First? Example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `AddStatus` method does not close the connection, which seems to be what EF is complaining about.

That said, you might also look at executing your stored procedure using [`Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand%28v=VS.103%29.aspx).  The syntax for passing parameters is a little different (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5475210/409259)):

```
var firstName = "John";
var id = 12;
var sql = @"Update [User] SET FirstName = {0} WHERE Id = {1}";
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, firstName, id);
```

Comment: You can't open a closed connection. I originally was closing it :)

Comment: @Dismissile, so you leave it open and EF complains that it has to be closed, and if you close it EF complains that it can't open it?  :D  Sounds like it would be easiest to use `ExecuteSqlCommand` (if it works in your case) and let EF manage the connection state.

Comment: Which I plan to use now. I didn't realize it existed.