# ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand doesn't recognise parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

What am I doing wrong here?

```
...
using (var ctx = ObjectContextManager<MyDataContext>.GetManager("MyDataContext"))
{
    var idsToUpdate = "2,3";

    var parameters = new[]
    {
         new SqlParameter("DesiredEndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = newUpperLimit,
         new SqlParameter("TasksToUpdate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = idsToUpdate
    };

    ctx.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("UPDATE dbo.Tasks SET DesiredEndDate = @DesiredEndDate WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM dbo.fn_Split(@TasksToUpdate, N','))", parameters);

    ctx.ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
}
...
```

I get the error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@DesiredEndDate".
>
> Must declare the scalar variable "@TasksToUpdate".

But I cannot see what is wrong with my code :/

Comment: Not sure about the error you are getting with `@DesiredEndDate` but that approach with `IN (@TasksToUpdate)` isn't going to work anyway.

Comment: I've already tested it by manually executing the query with hardcoded values. Can you explain why you think it's wrong?

Comment: It won't work. It will be the same as doing `Id IN ('1,2')` not the same as  `Id IN (1,2)`

Comment: You're right. Thanks for pointing it out. Updated. Still getting the same error though :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your code:

```
var parameters = new[]
{
     new SqlParameter("DesiredEndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = newUpperLimit,
     new SqlParameter("TasksToUpdate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = idsToUpdate
};
```

is not creating an array of `SqlParameter`s - it's actually create an array of the 2 `Value` properties. You can confirm this by changing your code to this (which will not compile):

```
var parameters = new SqlParameter[]
{
     new SqlParameter("DesiredEndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = newUpperLimit,
     new SqlParameter("TasksToUpdate", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = idsToUpdate
};
```

and this (which will compile)

```
var parameters = new SqlParameter[]
{
     new SqlParameter("DesiredEndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime),
     new SqlParameter("TasksToUpdate", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
};

parameters[0].Value = newUpperLimit;
parameters[1].Value = idsToUpdate;
```

You can also do this:

```
var param1 = new SqlParameter("DesiredEndDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
param1.Value = newUpperLimit;
var param2 = new SqlParameter("TasksToUpdate", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
param2.Value = idsToUpdate;

ctx.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("...", param1, param2);
```

Comment: Cool. I was sure I had done it the way I showed in the question before and it had worked. Thanks for the explanation. Turns out that the SqlParameters variables are unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

I still don't see why the @ParamName syntax doesn't work. But there is an alternative to this, which does work:

```
 ctx.ObjectContext
    .ExecuteStoreCommand(
          "UPDATE dbo.Tasks SET DesiredEndDate = {0} WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM dbo.fn_Split({1}, N','))",
          newUpperLimit, 
          idsToUpdate);
```

This has the added benefit that I don't need to create `SqlParameter`s.

Comment: You have got a possible SQL injection issue here though if `newUpperLimit` and `idsToUpdate` aren't guaranteed to be in a safe format.

Comment: There is no SQL injection possible here. Internally, ExecuteStoreCommand uses DbCommand. CreateParameter to pass the parameters. See Josh Gallagher's comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474264/how-to-pass-parameters-to-the-dbcontext-database-executesqlcommand-method.

Comment: Ah interesting. I didn't look that closely TBH. I saw the `{0}` and just thought you were doing string concatenation.