# What context to use in order to run raw query on simplemembership tables MVC 4 EF6

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to .Net MVC and I wanted to run a raw query on my UserInRoles table.

I think I will need a database context to run it.

I'm unsure what context to use. Can some one recommend me a direction to take? Currently, the `ObjectContext` does not allow me to instantiate without a connection string. Is directly grabbing the connection string from web config correct?

`Error  1   'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments`

```
 using (var ctx = new ObjectContext())
 {
     string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles (RoleId,UserId) values ("+chk+","+id+");";
     ExecuteSql(ctx,query);
 }
```

ExecuteSql is using ADO.net connections different from what EF recommends but I need to do this manual insert in order for this section to work.

```
    static void ExecuteSql(ObjectContext c, string sql)
    {
        var entityConnection = (System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection)c.Connection;
        DbConnection conn = entityConnection.StoreConnection;
        ConnectionState initialState = conn.State;
        try
        {
            if (initialState != ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Open();  // open connection if not already open
            using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (initialState != ConnectionState.Open)
                conn.Close(); // only close connection if not initially open
        }
    }
```

Comment: Executing raw SQL is a by-product of a context. If you only want to execute raw SQL, using a context adds huge overhead. But why can't you instantiate a context with a parameterless constructor? it should take the connection string from the config without any help unless you deliberately changed it not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ObjectContext`  ([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) requires you to provide a connection string to execute against. The ObjectContext is not your EF container but a context to query against a database and transform to objects. Because it is a generic query mechanism it does not know which connection string to use. In addition, your query is a simple insert query making the ObjectContext the wrong tool for the job. As the ObjectContext provides mapping mechanisms that you will not require I would suggest using your EF container to execute the query. This can be done by calling (sample code)

```
dbContainer.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query)
```

This command will grab your existing connection string from your configuration file and execute the query provided. Finally there is another option if you really want a `ObjectContext` without having to enter the connection string. You can do this by providing a wrapper, or static method to create an ObjectContext without the connection string. Such as.

Method 1: Wrapper (inheritance)

```
class MyObjectContext : ObjectContext
{
    public MyObjectContext()
        : base(MyObjectContext.connectionString)
    { }

    /// <summary>
    /// the connection string id in the config
    /// </summary>
    const string connectionStringID = "dbCon";

    /// <summary>
    /// gets the connection string
    /// </summary>
    static string connectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringID].ConnectionString
        }
    }
}
```

Method 2. Static Property (or method)

```
static ObjectContext New
{
    get
    {
        return new ObjectContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbCon"].ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Now personally I prefer method 1 (if i had to do this) as it also gives me the ability to extend this class to define my queries in one class such as.

```
class MyObjectContext : ObjectContext
{
    //.....
    public void Insert_UserInRole(string roleID, string id)
    {
        ///TODO DO: insert role
    }

    //.....
}
```

And can be called such as.

```
using (var context = new MyObjectContext())
{
    context.Insert_UserInRole("abc", "123");
}
```

[Just a thought]

**Important** In addition your query is begging for SQL Injection. Use "parameters" in your queries. Using parameters will prevent SQL inject atacks. Here is a SO topic regarding parameters. [How to pass parameters to the DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474264/how-to-pass-parameters-to-the-dbcontext-database-executesqlcommand-method)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, I asked this question almost 8 years ago. I am so surprised how much I've grown since then and these questions seem almost trivial to me now.