# Fire inline query in Entity framework for Oracle Connection?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I am new to EF.
Trying to fetch some record for a inline query ..

i have followed 
http://geekswithblogs.net/rgupta/archive/2010/06/23/entity-framework-v4-ndash-tips-and-tricks.aspx

Have dode

```
var lstStatInfo = new List<BISRCNCCYC>();
                using (var contextobj = new TADBEntities(_connStr, _scheName))
                {

                    string sql = "select * from MYTABLE where MYID = :MYID";
                    int id = 475;
                    var args = new DbParameter[] { new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "MYID", Value = "475" } };
                    var students = contextobj.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, id);
                    return lstStatInfo;
                }
```

Have even tried 
[How to pass parameters to the DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474264/how-to-pass-parameters-to-the-dbcontext-database-executesqlcommand-method)

but getting error ORA-00936: missing expression

I am trying to connect oracle not SQl ...what should be the correct way ?

Comment: Problem i am getting while adding parameter...how to add oracle parameter in ef context object

Answer (score 0):

change your

```
string sql = "select * from MYTABLE where MYID = {0}";
```

To

```
string sql = "select * from MYTABLE where MYID = :MYID";
```

Comment: @RahulChowdhury  do you need somethin like `myCommand1.Parameters.Add("some", 20)`

Comment: Its not creating command object its creating EF context object ..Can you please come with an example