# Updating a set of records in LINQ - All at once

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have several records that all need to be updated to the same value. If I was just using ADO.NET I could just call a stored procedure that updated them all at one ...

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myColumn = "XXXXXX"
WHERE filterColumn == 'YYY'
```

But since I am using Entity Framework I am wondering if their was a similar way to update a set of records at once without having to loop through each of the values and set them individually? Currently I am using..

```
from s in myTables
where s.filterColumn == 'YYY'
select s;

var results = s.ToList();

foreach (i in results){
  s.myColumn = "XXXXXX"
}
```

Is there a way to set the values all at once as in SQL?

I am using Entity Framework v6.1

Comment: you can execute [raw sql queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx) with EF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still execute sql command when using Entity Framework. Here is how to do it.

```
dbContext.Database.Connection.Open();
var cmd = dbContext.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE myTable
SET myColumn = @myColumn
WHERE filterColumn = @filterColumn";

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("myColumn", "XXXXXX"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("filterColumn", "YYY"));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: The `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` method is even easier: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5475210/124386

Answer (score 2):

The Entity Framework Extended Library includes batch update / delete functionality:
https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended

```
myTables.Update(
    s => s.filterColumn == "YYY",
    s => s.myColumn = "XXXXXX");
```

**NB:** This currently only supports SQL Server and SQL CE, although there is [a pull request to add MySQL support](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/pull/51).

Comment: Might be worth noting that EFE only really supports SQL Server.

Comment: @Aron - And SQL Server Compact :-)