# How to use LINQ on a join table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

The query I am trying to replicate in LINQ is:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM joinTable WHERE object1ID = input_parameter1_from_code 
AND object2ID = input_parameter2_from_code;
```

I have access to a IdentityDbContext, but it only contains references to the constituent objects' tables, not for the join table itself, so I don't know what to look for to try to get the result.

Alternatively, if I can just use this raw query, I would like to know how to do that as well.
Thank you.

Comment: what is `joinTable`? is it a table in your database? a view?

Comment: @GiladGreen yes it is a table in my database.

Comment: @GiladGreen yes it is the name of the plain regular table. It is actually called "AppRoleAppPrivileges" but I just made it as "joinTable" in my question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have in mind `many-to-many` relationship with implicit "link" ("join", "junction") table. Something like this (most likely you are speaking for `User` and `Role`, but that's not essential):

```
public class One
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Two> Twos { get; set; }
}

public class Two
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<One> Ones { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<One> Ones { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Two> Twos { get; set; }
}
```

Although you have no direct access to the link table, you can use either of the two "primary" tables combined with the navigation property of the other.

So, given

```
var db = new MyDbContext();
```

both

```
int count =
    (from one in db.Ones
     from two in one.Twos
     where one.Id == input_parameter1_from_code && two.Id == input_parameter2_from_code
     select new { one, two })
     .Count();
```

and

```
int count =
    (from two in db.Twos
     from one in two.Ones
     where one.Id == input_parameter1_from_code && two.Id == input_parameter2_from_code
     select new { one, two })
     .Count();
```

will produce identical SQL query similar to this:

```
SELECT
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[TwoOne] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE (1 = [Extent1].[One_Id]) AND (2 = [Extent1].[Two_Id])
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

which as you can see is against the link table.

Comment: Yes it is a many-to-many relationship table that was autogenerated from the model definitions. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In query syntax:

```
var amount = (from record in DBcontext.joinTable
              where record.object1ID = input_parameter1_from_code &&
                    record.object2ID = input_parameter2_from_code
              select record).Count();
```

In Method syntax:

```
var amount = DBcontext.joinTable
                      .Where(record => record.object1ID = input_parameter1_from_code &&
                                       record.object2ID = input_parameter2_from_code)
                      .Count();
```

Comment: I made a mistake in my question (now fixed) saying I had a DBcontext, but it is actually an IdentityDbContext. Additionally, I get an error saying the db context does not contain a definition for joinTable. Should joinTable be in some kind of string since it is a db table name?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Database.SqlQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679164(v=vs.113).aspx) method which accepts raw sql query along with the parameters that you need to use with your query and advantage of using `sql parameter` is to avoid `sql injection`.

Try like this:

```
var data = yourContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>(
    "SELECT count(*) FROM joinTable WHERE object1ID = @code1 AND object2ID = @code2",
    new SqlParameter("@code1", input_parameter1_from_code),
    new SqlParameter("@code2", input_parameter2_from_code)
);
```

Let me know if this didnt work for you :)

Comment: Thanks, a variation of this worked for another query. I had to replace the `yourContext.Database.SqlQuery<int>` to `yourContext.YourObject.SqlQuery` where YourObject is a model, and added a `.ToList()` before the `;' at the end. This was to return a list of objects, not just a count.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use that query with a DbContext. Take a look at the MSDN documentation over here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executequery(v=vs.110).aspx

It will be something like:

```
var Count = DbContext.ExecuteQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM joinTable where object1ID = input_parameter1_from_code 
AND object2ID = input_parameter2_from_code;");
```

Comment: I am trying this with IdentityDbContext so I had to change the query to `var Count = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.AppRoleAppPrivileges where AppRole_Id = "+roleId+" AND AppPrivilege_ID = " +privId+"; ");`, but now I get a Syntax error in the debugger, even without the `EXEC`

Comment: db.Database.ExecuteS‌​qlCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.AppRoleAppPrivil‌​eges where AppRole_Id = "+roleId+" AND AppPrivilege_ID = " +privId+"; ");

Comment: No, please don't do this, make sure you used a parameterized query.  see [How to pass parameters to the DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474264/how-to-pass-parameters-to-the-dbcontext-database-executesqlcommand-method)

Comment: Bob's right. It is definitely worth it to code right, it could be easier now but in the long run this code will cost you.

Comment: I will keep that in mind for the future when I use raw queries. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, even in case of link table

```
dbContext.CollectionOne.where(x => x.Id ==  1).SelectMany(x => x.Collection2).where(y => y.Id == 2).Count()
```